# How to format output into columns

Tags: java

How do I format my output into columns? I have a basic knowledge, but seem to be stuck on getting the format down. My goal is to get it to look like the format below.

```
Hour  Act1  Act2  Act3

1           Sleep

2           Sleep

3           Sleep

4           Sleep

5           Sleep

6           Sleep

7           Sleep

8           Sleep

9           Sleep

10

11

12    Eat

13    Eat

14    Eat

15

16                School

17                School

18                School

19                School

20                School

21                School

22                School

23

24
```

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DaySchedule {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Day Schedule

        String activity1, activity2, activity3;
        int eat, sleep, school, eatstart, eatend, sleepstart, sleepend, schoolstart, schoolend;
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter first daily activity: ");
        activity1=in.next();
        System.out.println("Enter total hours for activity one: ");
        eat=in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter starting hour for activity one: ");
        eatstart=in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter ending hour for activity one: ");
        eatend=in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter secound daily activity: ");
        activity2=in.next();
        System.out.println("Enter total hours for activity two: ");
        sleep=in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter stating hour for activity two: ");
        sleepstart=in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter ending hour for activity two: ");
        sleepend=in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter third daily activity: ");
        activity3=in.next();
        System.out.println("Enter total hours for activity three: ");
        school=in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter starting hour for activity three: ");
        schoolstart=in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter ending hour for activity three: ");
        schoolend= in.nextInt();

        int hour;
        int mins;
        System.out.println("Day Schedule");
        System.out.format("%-3s%-10s%-10s%-10s","Hour ","Activity1", "Activity2", "Activity3");
        System.out.format("%n");
        for (hour=1; hour<=24; ++hour);
        {
             System.out.format("%3d",hour);

             for (mins=1; mins<=59; ++mins)
                {
                    switch(mins)
                    {
              case 1: if (hour==eat)
                          System.out.printf("%-3s%-10s","",activity1);
                      break;
              case 2: if (hour==sleep)
                          System.out.format("%-3s%-10s%-10s","","",activity2);
                      break;
              case 3: if (hour==school)
                          System.out.format("%-3s%-10s%-10s%-10s","","","",activity3);
                      break;     



        }

    }

        System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The sleep is supposed to be under activity 2 and school under activity 3, messed up when posted.

Comment: Hint: if you haven't heard about **arrays** yet, you might want to study them now. Having variables named something1, something2, ... and then having code that manipulates each of those thingies on its own is simply spoken bad on my levels. Using arrays, you could reduce the amount of code required for this exercise dramatically. Also consider breaking up your large method into several smaller ones - it really makes reading your code **easier**. Putting too much code into one method adds a lot of potential "confusion" to the mind of any reader ...

Comment: Look up the class StringBuilder and use it to append a TAB and either the value of the variable or some more TABs/whitespace, if it's empty.